# Python globals var different inside class when imported

Tags: python, class, scope, global-variables

This is clearly a scope or import issue of some kind, but I can't figure it out.  Something like:

```
classes.py

class Thing(object):

    @property
    def global_test(self):
        return the_global
```

And then...

```
test.py

from classes import Thing

global the_global
the_global = 'foobar'

t = Thing()
t.global_test
```

:(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "classes.py", line 4, in global_test
    return the_global
NameError: global name 'the_global' is not defined
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"global" in Python is a variable accessible in top level within module.

This message:

```
NameError: global name 'the_global' is not defined
```

raised within `classes.py` means you do not have a global named `the_global` within your `classes.py` file.

**Python modules do not share global variables**. (well, not in the way you want them to share)

Answer (score 0):

The 'global' variables only defines a variable as global inside the scope of the module
where it is used. You can not use 'global' here to access a variable outside the module
scope of the 'classes' module.

The proper solution here if you have to deal with global defines or so: move the "global"
variables into a dedicated module and use a proper import statement to import the variables
into your 'classes' module.

myvars.py:

```
MY_GLOBAL_VAR = 42
```

classes.py:

```
import myvars

class Thing():

   def method(self):
       return myvars.MY_GLOBAL_VAR # if you need such a weird pattern for whatever reason
```

Comment: Thanks, the "weird" pattern was for demonstration purposes, of course.